# How to script user input using Firebase Game Loop testing on Android?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-test-lab

I'm interested in scripting some user actions for regression testing my app as I publish updates. I have read [this firebase doc](https://firebase.google.com/docs/test-lab/android/get-started?hl=nl) and [this Google page on Game Loop](https://firebase.google.com/docs/test-lab/android/game-loop) and I clearly am not getting it.

Am I supposed to script the user actions I want to mimic by writing Java code here?:

[image: Screenshot from firebase.google.com]

I thought I would be able to run the app on a device and record user actions as a scripting mechanism. Is that not how this works?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Game loops don't help you script your app, they help you *run* your already scripted app. There's no API within game loops for automating actions; that Java snippet would help a running game loop determine what "scenario" (integer ID) the app was launched as.

If your app is a native Android application (i.e. you're not using the NDK or a game engine), you could consider [recording your user actions as part of a Roboscript](https://firebase.google.com/docs/test-lab/android/robo-ux-test#scripting). Firebase Test Lab supports running Robo tests, which could reliably replay those actions using that Roboscript as input.

Comment: Ah, thanks, I was afraid of that. I can't use Roboscript because the interface is a webview that displays dynamic content. If I understand Roboscript I would have to have widgets with resource IDs to click on, not a javascript button.

Comment: Also, Compose apps won't support Robo scripts. Since we are talking about production builds (Game loop is used by Pre-launch reports on Google Play), would shipping a "scripted app" work from the security point of view?